# Why is this a failed Audit? I thought questions should include the error not a link to a screenshot

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I failed a Close question Audit here which includes a link to a screenshot of the error:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/33923100

I choose 'Needs details or Clarity' because the question included a link to a screenshot instead of the actual error. Was I wrong in this thinking?

Comment: Looks like bad luck, it was an issue that affected a bunch of users so they upvoted and it got turned into an audit.

Comment: You could have chosen to improve the question yourself by editing it.  The fact it's been closed since your audit shouldn't be considered.  So while the question was closed, it could have easily been edited, and improved.

Comment: This _does_ have the error as text: it's in the title (well...most of it...they should have added the rest).  The screenshot mostly supplements that.

Comment: @SecurityHound pretty sure that we shouldn't convert image to text ourselves but instead let OP do it. Also, asking a reviewer to retype 3 lines of error message is definitely not reasonable.

Comment: @Dada - In-line the screenshot was enough

Comment: If I failed the audit because I said it should be closed, then why was is it closed? Some of these audits are a bit unclear and seem to go against the person who's trying to support the site.

Comment: @Rich The quality of audits has been long discussed, condemned, ridiculed and otherwise disqualified. They're automatically picked, so there is zero guarantee to how they are going to play out. You can just as easily run into an audit that is completely misleading because for example a question was closed for the wrong reasons. The software can't verify that this is the case, it'll simply expect you to make the same wrong choice. They don't exist to test your reviewing skills, they exist to halt robo reviewers who just click "next next next next".

Comment: @Rich - When you viewed the audit the question wasn't closed. Once you realized it was an audit, and had failed the audit, did you downvote the question and vote to close it? *The experience you had is the reason I open reviews in another tab.*